# Add missing values to raster data set [expand, not fill holes] in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, nodata, fill

I'm relatively new to QGIS and have run into the following problem.

I am using a raster soil data set that was cut to the country border. However, since the cut was rough and my research area is set along the country border, I have a lot of missing data around the northern and eastern edges. I would like to fill these data using interpolation from the data that is there (which is itself interpolated data).
In other words, I would like to extend the raster data set to fully match my research area (marked lightgreen).

[image: raster area shortage img]

I have tried a number of tools, but none have given me the result I need.

- r.neighbors
- LecoS Match two landscapes
- gdal fill nodata
- gdal fill nodata, including a validity mask whereby the "missing" cells were 1 and all other cells 0

I'd like to solve using QGIS, but if necessary I can use ArcGIS on a lab computer to fix it if that's a lot easier.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, you're not looking to intrpolate, but instead to extrapolate, which is not going to do your data quality any favors. You may need to find a new data source that isn't damaged.

Comment: That's not what I was hoping for, but at least it's a clear answer. Thank you.